# Redirect when htaccess login fails

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, download, password-protection, .htpasswd

i wonder how to set a redirect rule when user is typing wrong username or password.

currently the .htaccess is placed in `/path/to/my/dir/website/dlfiles`

The user is on the website on path `/path/to/my/dir/website/` with url `mywebsite.com/downloads`

When user tries to download file from `/path/to/my/dir/website/dlfiles/myfile_123.zip` the user gets the htaccess login alert. When typing wrong username or password it results in "**Unauthorized**" Error page but i want the user to directly go back to the page he was when clicking on download-link, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP you could use the header() function.

```
<?php
header('Location: /path/to/my/dir/website/mywebsite.com/downloads'); //redirect on register
?>
```

You can add this to your "Unauthorized" Error page" which is probably found on your server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, where i can find the "Unauthorized" Error page" on the server? Additional the /downloads in the url is not an existing folder its a rewrite rule from the cms, is it possible to redirect to a url instead of path? Or is it possible when clicking a downloadlink to stay on the origin site instead of redirecting to downloaded file?

Comment: No problem, I will try to help you the best I can. 
1. Your "Unauthorized" Error page" will really depend on your server, if you are using a hosting service it is probably called something along the lines of 403.html. You should just grab the URL/file name from the URL bar when you enter the wrong username or password just like you said in your question.
-2. Sure redirecting to url is really simple ```header('Location: http://www.example.com/'); ``` 
3. Sadly I cannot help with this, I tried on my website but couldn't quite manage and didn't try again. header() can achieve this.